# how to get the Ram Speed?

Tags: c#

hi i need to find out the RAM Speed...anybody help me

Comment: Sorry about the close vote - I didn't see the C# tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use WMI.
This will give you speed and many more parameters:

```
On Error Resume Next 
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory") 
For Each objItem in colItems 

Wscript.Echo "Bank Label: " & objItem.BankLabel 
Wscript.Echo "Capacity: " & objItem.Capacity 
Wscript.Echo "Data Width: " & objItem.DataWidth 
Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description 
Wscript.Echo "Device Locator: " & objItem.DeviceLocator 
Wscript.Echo "Form Factor: " & objItem.FormFactor 
Wscript.Echo "Hot Swappable: " & objItem.HotSwappable 
Wscript.Echo "Manufacturer: " & objItem.Manufacturer 
Wscript.Echo "Memory Type: " & objItem.MemoryType 
Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name 
Wscript.Echo "Part Number: " & objItem.PartNumber 
Wscript.Echo "Position In Row: " & objItem.PositionInRow 
Wscript.Echo "Speed: " & objItem.Speed 
Wscript.Echo "Tag: " & objItem.Tag 
Wscript.Echo "Type Detail: " & objItem.TypeDetail 

Next
```

Comment: Actually I missed the C# tag too.
Still - use WMI for this, just change to C# syntax

Comment: Does it give the real-time speed? Is it read speed or write speed? I tried finding out in its documentation. But that doesn't contain much information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/155174-c%23-wmi-physical-memory-speed/) post answers your question? It is a question itself but it'll point you in the right direction (WMI is the way to go here).