# How to get RAM speed in windows 8 and above

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, performance, hardware

I am currently using WMI in windows 8.1 with Management object :

```
Dim Mos = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT speed FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory")
Dim _Speed
For Each objMgmt In Mos.Get
    _Speed = objMgmt("speed")
Next
```

But it's showing nothing. Since there are various speed of ram within DDR3. I want to know if the ram in my pc or laptop is of

```
DDR3 1033 
DDR3 1333 
DDR3 1600 
DDR3 1800
```

Is there any other code to get the speed of ram in windows 8 and above ?

Answer (score -1):

Yup, there is an another way of getting this done, by using the same WMI, but this is a different approach and works in my both computers windows 8 & windows 10

1.Remember to place `Imports System.Management` as shown below, otherwise the code won't run.
2.Please create a `textbox` called `textbox1` in form1

```
Imports System.Management 

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim proc_query As String = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory"
        Dim proc_searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(proc_query)
        For Each info As ManagementObject In proc_searcher.Get()
            textbox1.Text = "Speed of Your RAM is  " & info.Properties("Speed").Value.ToString()
        Next info


    End Sub
End Class
```

If this is a solution please select this answer as accepted :), if you still can't get it to work, I'll try to help, just comment below :)

Comment: i have already done that. But it didn't worked. Speed is Null or blank. Have you tried the code in Windows 8.1 ?

Answer (score -2):

I would use WMI.

```
On Error Resume Next 
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "            {impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from     Win32_PhysicalMemory") 
For Each objItem in colItems 

Wscript.Echo "Bank Label: " & objItem.BankLabel 
Wscript.Echo "Capacity: " & objItem.Capacity 
Wscript.Echo "Data Width: " & objItem.DataWidth 
Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description 
Wscript.Echo "Device Locator: " & objItem.DeviceLocator 
Wscript.Echo "Form Factor: " & objItem.FormFactor 
Wscript.Echo "Hot Swappable: " & objItem.HotSwappable 
Wscript.Echo "Manufacturer: " & objItem.Manufacturer 
Wscript.Echo "Memory Type: " & objItem.MemoryType 
Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name 
Wscript.Echo "Part Number: " & objItem.PartNumber 
Wscript.Echo "Position In Row: " & objItem.PositionInRow 
Wscript.Echo "Speed: " & objItem.Speed 
Wscript.Echo "Tag: " & objItem.Tag 
Wscript.Echo "Type Detail: " & objItem.TypeDetail 

Next
```

(based on [how to get the Ram Speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093248/how-to-get-the-ram-speed))

Comment: No its not working. Showing BLANK in Speed. Try it yourself. I tried in windows8 and windows 8.1

Comment: I also tried to run as administrator, but its showing only BLANK speed.

Comment: @ErMayank Then, it's your problem. Works for me.

Comment: @ErMayank Also, please include more code. The problem might not be with the line you included.

Comment: `Then, it's your problem` - Not very helpful. Are you even using Windows 8? -- Also, VB.NET IsNot VBScript.

Comment: OP isn't asking for script. This clearly isn't `vb.net` and posting a solution other than what the OP is working in is not relevant. Also you said to use WMI, the OP is using WMI already. Your post is clearly ***not addressing the issue***. It should be removed all together as it's lacking details. Maybe a comment asking questions would suffice before throwing out code would have been a wise choice? Also copy another answer and posting it is right either, you could have made a comment with recommendation for the link.

Comment: I have 2 DDR3 1600 ram in my laptop. I just want this 1600 value by code. I have Formatted my laptop and re-installed windows 8.1 and visual studio. but its showing the same blank value in speed. Is there any other code ?